# For sandboxing, is there a way to run TypeScript directly in the browser?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to run TypeScript directly in the browser (for quick sandboxing purposes)?

Something like this:

```
<script type="typescript"></script>
```

I don't want to use parcel.

Is there a script which I can load that will run the ts compiler in the browser?

```
<script src="https://typescript-loader.com/index.js"
<script type="typescript"></script>
```

Comment: No. It is not built into any browser and is not native like JavaScript is.

Comment: You could use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone, then webpack the plugin at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript so you can include it on the page, then register the plugin, then use a `<script type="text/babel" data-plugins="typescript">` tag and write your typescript in that. It's probably easier to just build your typescript, but it's not as much fun.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but this might be the closest thing: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/